# Can not open serial port using PHP

Tags: php, serial-port

I am working on to send request to VSP200 device, my device is connected to com port8 of windows machine. I am using `fopen()` of PHP to open the com port, but I am getting an error

```
Warning: fopen(COM8:) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream
```

can you please tell me, what is wrong in my code,

```
$fp = fopen ("COM8:", "w+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo 'not open';
}
else{
    echo 'port is open for write<br/>';
    $string .= '<STX>C30C10178C10100C103110606C103081000C10100C10101C100<ETX>';
    fputs ($fp, $string );
    echo $string;
    fclose ($fp);
}
$fp = fopen ("COM8:", "r+");
if (!$fp) {
    echo 'not open for read';
}
else{
    echo '<br/> port is open for read<br/>';
    $buffer = fread($fp, 128 );
    echo $buffer;
    fclose ($fp);
}
```

Comment: Hi, was this ever solved? I tried your code and it seems to hang at ` $buffer = fread($fp, 128 );`

Answer (score 1):

You should not include the trailing colon in the port name:

```
$fp = fopen ("COM8", "w+");
```