# How do i send message via PHP using SIM800c USB Modem

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, sim800

Hi I'm currently having this script

```
<?php

    //SMS via GSM Modem - A PHP class to send SMS messages via a GSM modem attached to the computers serial port.
    
    //Windows only (tested on XP with PHP 5.2.6)
    //Tested with the EZ863 (Telit GE863) GSM modementer code here
    //Requires that PHP has permission to access "COM" system device, and system "mode" command
    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    //Example
    
    $gsm_send_sms = new gsm_send_sms();
    $gsm_send_sms->debug = true;
    $gsm_send_sms->port = 'COM8';
    $gsm_send_sms->baud = 19200;
    $gsm_send_sms->init();
    
    $status = $gsm_send_sms->send('09360403533', 'testing 123');
    if ($status) {
        echo "Message sent\n";
    } else {
        echo "Message not sent\n";
    }
    
    
    
    $gsm_send_sms->close();
    
    
    //Send SMS via serial SMS modem
    class gsm_send_sms {
    
        public $port = 'COM8';
        public $baud = 115200;
    
        public $debug = false;
    
        private $fp;
        private $buffer;
    
        //Setup COM port
        public function init() {
    
            $this->debugmsg("Setting up port: \"{$this->port} @ \"{$this->baud}\" baud");
    
            exec("MODE {$this->port}: BAUD={$this->baud} PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);
    
            if ($retval != 0) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to setup COM port, check it is correct');
            }
    
            $this->debugmsg(implode("\n", $output));
    
            $this->debugmsg("Opening port");
    
            //Open COM port
            $this->fp = fopen($this->port . ':', 'r+');
    
            //Check port opened
            if (!$this->fp) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to open port \"{$this->port}\"");
            }
    
            $this->debugmsg("Port opened");
            $this->debugmsg("Checking for responce from modem");
    
            //Check modem connected
            fputs($this->fp, "AT\r");
    
            //Wait for ok
            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);
    
            if (!$status) {
                throw new Exception('Did not receive responce from modem');
            }
    
            $this->debugmsg('Modem connected');
    
            //Set modem to SMS text mode
            $this->debugmsg('Setting text mode');
            fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGF=1\r");
    
            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 5);
    
            if (!$status) {
                throw new Exception('Unable to set text mode');
            }
    
            $this->debugmsg('Text mode set');
    
        }
    
        //Wait for reply from modem
        private function wait_reply($expected_result, $timeout) {
    
            $this->debugmsg("Waiting {$timeout} seconds for expected result");
    
            //Clear buffer
            $this->buffer = '';
    
            //Set timeout
            $timeoutat = time() + $timeout;
    
            //Loop until timeout reached (or expected result found)
            do {
    
                $this->debugmsg('Now: ' . time() . ", Timeout at: {$timeoutat}");
    
                $buffer = fread($this->fp, 1024);
                $this->buffer .= $buffer;
    
                usleep(200000);//0.2 sec
    
                $this->debugmsg("Received: {$buffer}");
    
                //Check if received expected responce
                if (preg_match('/'.preg_quote($expected_result, '/').'$/', $this->buffer)) {
                    $this->debugmsg('Found match');
                    return true;
                    //break;
                } else if (preg_match('/\+CMS ERROR\:\ \d{1,3}\r\n$/', $this->buffer)) {
                    return false;
                }
    
            } while ($timeoutat > time());
    
            $this->debugmsg('Timed out');
    
            return false;
    
        }
    
        //Print debug messages
        private function debugmsg($message) {
    
            if ($this->debug == true) {
                $message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\n\t]%", '', $message);
                echo $message . "\n";
            }
    
        }
    
        //Close port
        public function close() {
    
            $this->debugmsg('Closing port');
            var_dump($this->fp);
            fclose($this->fp);
    
        }
    
        //Send message
        public function send($tel, $message) {
            //Filter tel
            $tel = preg_replace("%[^0-9\+]%", '', $tel);
    
            //Filter message text
            //$message = preg_replace("%[^\040-\176\r\n\t]%", '', $message);
    
            $this->debugmsg("Sending message \"{$message}\" to \"{$tel}\"");
    
            //Start sending of message
            fputs($this->fp, "AT+CMGS=\"{$tel}\"\r");
    
            //Wait for confirmation
            $status = $this->wait_reply("\r\n> ", 5);
    
            if (!$status) {
                //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
                $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation from modem');
                return false;
            }
    
            //Send message text
             fputs($this->fp, $message);
    
    
            //Send message finished indicator
            fputs($this->fp, chr(26));
    
            //Wait for confirmation
            $status = $this->wait_reply("OK\r\n", 180);
    
            if (!$status) {
                //throw new Exception('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
                $this->debugmsg('Did not receive confirmation of messgage sent');
                return false;
            }
    
            $this->debugmsg("Message sent");
    
            return true;
    
        }
    
    }

?>
```

and this is giving me this error

```
Setting up port: "COM8 @ "19200" 
baud Status for device COM8: ----------------------- 
Baud: 19200 
Parity: None 
Data Bits: 8 
Stop Bits: 1 
Timeout: OFF 
XON/XOFF: OFF 
CTS handshaking: OFF 
DSR handshaking: OFF 
DSR sensitivity: OFF 
DTR circuit: ON 
RTS circuit: ON 
Opening port Warning: fopen(COM8:): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bls\visitor\send-bls.php on line 64
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unable to open port "COM8" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bls\visitor\send-bls.php:68 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\bls\visitor\send-bls.php(18): gsm_send_sms->init() #1
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bls\visitor\send-bls.php on line 68

I'm new to this and i want to learn more, I'd need some advice to some of you professionals.

I Tried different types of COM Port from my device manager and still give me the same error.

Comment: Looks to me like your machine doesn't have a COM8: configured, or it's already in use. You can configure the port numbers from Device Manager. If something else is already using the port you'll need to find out what, and make sure it releases it.

Comment: Hey @TangentiallyPerpendicular, i tried to change my COM PORT and configured it but still gave me this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not open serial port using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359724/can-not-open-serial-port-using-php)

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular unfortunately no

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i tried the link you've sent and it just display
Setting up port: "COM8 @ "115200" baud Status for device COM8: ----------------------- Baud: 115200 Parity: None Data Bits: 8 Stop Bits: 1 Timeout: OFF XON/XOFF: OFF CTS handshaking: OFF DSR handshaking: OFF DSR sensitivity: OFF DTR circuit: ON RTS circuit: ON Opening port Port opened Checking for responce from modem Waiting 5 seconds for expected